# Автофокус в форме пользовательского поиска Google

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, focus, google-customsearch-api

### 1. Кратко

У меня не получается правильно поставить автофокус в форму [**Пользовательского Поиска Google**](https://cse.google.ru/).

---

### 2. Ограничения

#### 2.1. Сайт

Допустимы любые решения, подходящие для статических сайтов, то есть:

1. если в решении задействованы JQuery или любые другие JavaScript-библиотеки — ничего страшного;
2. к сожалению, не подходят решения, работающие только для динамических сайтов.

#### 2.2. Браузеры

Желательна поддержка последних версий современных браузеров.

Совместимость с Internet Explorer и старыми версиями браузеров совсем не обязательна.

---

### 3. MCVE

- [**Демонстрация на Codepen**](https://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/ErwpPr)
- HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.3.1/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- [INFO] HTML5 validation, see:
    https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/customsearch/XE-cs3_oVuY/ohwVpwEUAgAJ and
    https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element#html5 -->
    <div class="gcse-search" data-enableHistory="true" data-enableAutoComplete="true" data-autoCompleteMaxCompletions="10" data-enableOrderBy="false"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

- CoffeeScript:

```coffee
# Google Custom Search script
# Don't change it
do ->
    cx = '013024336414733191742:sps98skj394'
    gcse = document.createElement('script')
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript'
    gcse.async = true
    gcse.src = 'https://cse.google.com/cse.js?cx=' + cx
    s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]
    s.parentNode.insertBefore gcse, s
    return
```

---

### 4. Не предлагать

#### 4.1. Таймаут

Вроде бы автофокус работает с использованием таймаута.

```coffee
# Timeout
setTimeout (->
    document.getElementById('gsc-i-id1').focus()
    return
), 1500
```

- [**код**](https://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/omGMZg)
- [**демонстрация**](https://codepen.io/Kristinita/full/omGMZg)

Но:

1. Бывает, форма пользовательского поиска загружается дольше, чем обычно, → в консоли браузера появляется ошибка.

   ```
   TypeError: document.getElementById(…) is null
   ```

   И из-за этого могут ломаться тесты.
2. Ставить большой таймаут, чтобы автофокус появился наверняка, не хотелось бы. Собственно, автофокус нужен, чтобы пользователь сразу и без лишних движений вводил поисковый запрос. Постоянное долгое время ожидания автофокуса, отнимающее время пользователей, нежелательно.

Т. е., видимо, лучше, чтобы автофокус применялся после загрузки формы.

---

### 5. Не помогло

#### 5.1. autofocus

`input` генерируется динамически → просто [**добавить атрибут `autofocus`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3383468/5951529) не получается. В панели управления Guctom Search также нет настройки автофокуса.

#### 5.2. $(document).ready()

[**Пробовал гуглить подобные вопросы**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWCAX.png) → в ответах (как [**здесь**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20467949/5951529) или [**здесь**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19291707/5951529)) предлагают обернуть скрипт в [**`$(document).ready()`**](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) (или это же [**без JQuery**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20749758/5951529)), чтобы он выполнялся после готовности страницы.

```coffee
# $(document).ready()
$(document).ready ->
    $('#gsc-i-id1').focus()
    return
```

- [**код**](https://codepen.io/Kristinita/pen/PVJdoR)
- [**демонстрация**](https://codepen.io/Kristinita/full/PVJdoR)